# Issue with Multiple contacts with multiple accounts in my saleforce org. How to avoid it?

Tags: accountcontactrelation

I have a quick question, I have multiple contacts ( for the same person ) and those contacts are associated to multiple accounts. This is what I want to achieve...one contact should be associate to multiple accounts.We have also noticed that same person on the multiple contacts have attachments liked to the different accounts he is associated with.
How to make the same person on multiple contact to a single contact? What is the best way to do this?. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good way to achieve relating contact to multiple accounts is by using Standard functionality like Account Contact Relationship, there's a lot of documentation about it.
[Contacts to Multiple Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=shared_contacts_overview.htm&type=5)

Regarding merging contacts there's also a standard merge functionality, you can take a look [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contacts_merge.htm&type=5).